# Persistence Framework Making 'Batch' Calls, Need 'RPC' Call

Tags: java, sql-server, jtds, spring-mybatis

I'm attempting to make an RPC database call using MyBatis persistence framework alongside using the JTDS jdbc driver.  The problem is that they are being sent as batch calls to sqlserver.  Here is an example of the mapper xml using a stored proc that takes 2 parameters:

```
<select     id="doSomething"
            parameterType="com.myCompany.Member"
            resultMap="memberMap"
            statementType="CALLABLE" >
            {call dbo.getAMember_sp  (#{mId,jdbcType=INTEGER,mode=IN}, 1)}
</select>
```

Does anyone know how to make this send as RPC, rather than BATCH?